# Schedule regular interval email with attached PDF (which looks same as UI) REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, scheduled-tasks, html-email

We have a UI page that contains a number of charts built using the Rechart library.
There is a functionality for PDF generation that creates the PDF which looks 90% same as UI page.

We have used html2canvas, jspdf (picking rendered charts unique id from html and arranging them in PDF )

Now, new requirement is to schedule the same PDF report at regular intervals.

One solution is to bring PDF generation code to backend. (in this chart creation code will be duplicated (PROBLEM: UI will have react rechart, In backend we should look for other charting library )

However we want to reuse the react components of charts.
Any suggestions ??

we are looking at puppeteer and SSR but not sure about the approach.

Comment: when you generate pdf, where do you store the file?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good idea to explore Selenium or any libraries based on Selenium to automate the process.
Selenium provides the option to run your web app in headless browser mode (ie, Selenium would be able to access the DOM elements without actually having to open a browser window). The good thing is you can schedule the Selenium script in any server, as you don't need access to the front-end or backend code to run it. It's just mimicking the user actions.

The script you write would essentially be to automate whatever you are doing in front end.

Hope this helps.